# When toggeling overflow property on parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

[The example Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dctxy2w6/2/).

A container with `height:auto` contains items with the `width:100%`. When a button is clicked, the list changes to `height:400px` and `overlow-y:scroll`. When clicked again, the items have no longer `width:100%`. They remain the width as the scrollbar would still be visible.

Is there a css-way of fixing this? I would like to avoid a jquery-hack.

This is what I see on Windows, Chrome 52:

After page load:

[image: After page load]

After a first click on Toggle:

[image: After a first click on Toggle]

After a second click on Toggle:

[image: After a first click on Toggle]

Thank you so much!

?!? Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Okaaayy..?!?

```
.scroll{
  height:400px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle works for me.. what browser are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Chrome 52 on Win. Have you clicked "toggle" twice? The items remain narrower after the scrollbar removal.

Comment: You're right. Working fine on Firefox.

Comment: I've clicked multiple times, and I'm not seeing that behaviour on Chrome 51 (Mac) and Safari. There is a difference between operating systems here, because scroll bars differ across platforms, but I don't have access to Windows for testing right now.

Comment: I see. Ideas for fixes? Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you post an image of what you see when the scrollbar is gone and the width is incorrect? I can try and "guess" some more bulletproof CSS.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dctxy2w6/6/ Is this good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Google Chrome. The children element loose their initial width when scrollbar is added however the calculated width has no change when the element is inspected.

As a CSS hack you can hide X-overflow in the container to prevent children from resizing when scroll bar is added.

Be careful this trick may practically fail if the content of items are too long and overflow the container.

```js
$("#toggle-scroll").on("click touchstart", function(){
 $("#list").toggleClass("scroll");
});
```

```css
#list{
  background-color:#808000;
  width:300px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.item{
  background-color:#555;color:#efefef;
  padding:4px;margin:1px;
}
.scroll{
  height:400px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
.btn{
  display:inline-block
  padding:15px;
  margin:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle-scroll" class="btn">Toggle Scrollbar</button>

<div id="list">

  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>
  <div class="item">Entry XYZ</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Very good. Thanks, also for the warning with long items. I'll take care.